# xDebug not working for only one project on PHPStorm

Tags: magento, phpstorm, xdebug

I regularly use xDebug on my projects without any problems although I have one project which I've started developing a Magento Module on and xDebug is not working on it.  It does still work on other projects though.

I can see xDebug in my phpinfo.php file.

xDebug seems to be running on port 9000.

```
$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :9000
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17261/java
```

I'm using this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) to start listening to start using xDebug.

I don't understand why xDebug will work on other projects but not this one, any advice very much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Interestingly when I added the URL of the project I'm trying debug to the PHPStorm settings of another project which xDebug works fine on, by going File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP Servers, xDebug kind of works.  Both projects are Magento Apps so have same directory/file structure.

[image]

With this setting Xdebug breaks in that project but with the warning.

> The script '/var/www/example/index.php' is outside the project.

If I try adding this setting to the project I'm trying to debug, nothing happens.

Comment: Collect standard xdebug log and see what it says first.

Comment: @LazyOne, where can I find the xdebug log? It's not in `/var/log/`

Comment: You have to enable it and specify the path in php.ini -- http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log . By default no logs gets collected.

Comment: @LazyOne, strangly this value was already set `xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log` but no file is there.

Comment: 1) Have you restarted your web server (most of them requires for PHP to pick up new settings) 2) Can you confirm via `phpinfo()` output that the setting is there (in case if you have edited the wrong file: remember: on Linux/Mac you most likely will have different ini files for CLI and Apache) 3) This simply could mean that A) access rights (unlikely) and B) xdebug does not see it as debug request. If it's 3.B .. then see if `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` (or placing `xdebug_break();` in your code) will make any difference

Comment: Yes I restarted my webserver, I can see `xdebug.remote_log` in the phpinfo.php file, it refers to the same file /var/log/xdebug.log.  `xdebug_break();` did not do anything.  I recursively put 777 permissions on the entire project directory and the owner is www-data as per the the other projects in which it works.

Comment: Well .. it's odd then. In my experience -- xdebug log should be created as long as xdebug sees the request .. or special "break-here" PHP code. if it does not -- then I do not know. Possibly (just a random thought as I have seen such situation in real live in one of the threads on forum) that you are disabling/altering xdebug settings when app is already running? No other ideas, sorry. I mean -- it could be wrong path (symbolic link etc) but it should still generate the log.

Comment: BTW -- did you try with `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` as well? What if you put breakpoint in completely wrong file (or code block) that never gets executed by mistake....

Comment: @LazyOne, yea just tried `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1`, no change.  Did you see the update to my question?  Thanks for your help, this is a real head scratcher.

Comment: Please delete both of these server entries in this problematic project and try again. Or go even more radical -- delete `.idea` subfolder (project settings) while project is closed  in IDE and start with this project from scratch (open project root using `Open` and point to the project root folder.

Comment: BTW -- what web server do you have there? What do you have for `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` (or whatever that key is)?